# How to fix "Could not open lock file" because "Permission denied"?

Tags: dpkg

Whenever trying to install any software and update manger,

I get an error stating

```
Package operation failed
The installation or removal of a software package failed
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I got this result:

```
conan51xd@conan51xd-Lenovo-B470:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for conan51xd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
conan51xd@conan51xd-Lenovo-B470:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and post its output in your question by editing it.

Comment: a `sudo apt-get -f install` entered into the terminal often works but tijybba is right; post the output of `apt-get update` if my tip does not work.

Comment: The best advice is to **reboot** , and try it will run just fine. Don't use update manager , Ubuntu software center or apt-get through command line at the same time.

Comment: yes,I know,I don't have use all of them at same times but the problem is when I finish updata,I will get this every times.

Comment: Hey you forgot the main keyword there , it should be `sudo apt-get update`. Thats the answer.

Comment: well you posted the output of `sudo apt-get -f install` not what i asked  ,anyway  i guess `sudo apt-get update` will run fine. Let us know if it works.

Comment: this should be market as duplicated of this http://askubuntu.com/q/427479/169736

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Run this command: 
`sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists{,july12}` 

`sudo apt-get update` 
Then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: This potentially can damage your system.

Comment: The answer was written assuming apt package utility. This software has enough code to take care of situations where some other process (mv in this case) fiddles with the directory where apt-get was writing/trying to write (/var/lib/apt/lists here). And if any software being installed on Un*x system doesn't have this safety, we should start writing an if statement to take care of it

Answer (score 47):

> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are
>   you root?

This line says you are not authorized to install/update. You need to be root to do it....

You can add `sudo` before `apt-get` or you can do `sudo -s` to be root.

Example: `sudo apt-get update`

> or

`sudo -s` will consider you as root until you close your terminal.

Then

`apt-get update`

Comment: I got the error with running `sudo apt update && apt upgrade`, where `sudo` was missing from the 2nd `apt` statement.

Comment: `sudo -s` is the command which solves my year long problem on MacOS !! thanks ~!

Answer (score 3):

1. `sudo -s` (gives the root access)
2. `apt-get update` (get the updates)
3. `apt-get upgrade` (upgrades the system)

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` doesn't work on every system so run the commands separately.

Comment: This isn't different than previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, this worked for me:

> This error indicates that you (or some program/script) changed the
> permissions of the file /var/lib/dpkg/status. Please change them back
> via: "sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/dpkg/status" in order to fix the issue.

I ended up opening terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

navigating to the folders/files, and changing permissions to

> ME - FOLDER:FULL ACCESS / FILES: READ WRITE
>
> ROOT - FOLDER: FULL ACCESS / FILES: READ ONLY

The problem came when my permissions got screwed when trying to fix a kernel issue I had with an Nvidia driver... but that's another story..

I hope this helps...