# Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Tags: apt

I get this error in Lubuntu 12.04 when I try to update in terminal:

```
$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: @AvatarParto it wasn't a duplicate of the above link you marked.There was an another one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hahah. This is ironic, you commented that it wasn't a duplicate then marked it as a duplicate?